# Validating input type text after Check Box Selections

Tags: javascript

I have been learning js from javascript in  10 simple steps.On task 104, there is the task of validating  input type text after Check Box Selections. However i have the confusion over how to grab the textfield after the checkbox is checked.After the checking whether the checkbox is checked, i tried to grab the textfield with syntax as `formName.TextareafieldName`.

However in the book, the syntax followed is as `form.formName.TextareafieldName`. While outputting in browser, it shows that only checkbox is checked but cannot grab textfiled showing ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.My code is follows.

```
<form name="myForm" action="js_form_validation_with_inputcheckbox.html"
 onSubmit="return checkForm(this);">
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="Checked"> Check Here<br>
    If checked, enter your name:
    <input type="text" name="myText"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And the script here:

```
<script>
function checkList(check) {
  if (check.checked) {
    if (myForm.myText.value.length == 0) {
      window.alert("You have checked the check box;you must provide your name.");
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function checkForm(formObj) {
  return checkList(formObj.myField.value);
}
</script>
```

I would highly appreciate if anyone can clear my confusion.

Comment: Generalising the problem will give you correct way to approach for solution, for example, you need text field, try searching for it in google like, "javascript finding text fields", (result of search https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=iIimVKb4FNKGoAOs8oHIBw&gws_rd=ssl#q=javascript+finding+text+fields)

Comment: Do you mean something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/n6je4pj5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *checkForm* you are passing `formObj.myField.value`, but there is no control named *myField*. Perhaps you meant *myCheck*?

Also, the *checkList* function seems to want a control, not a value, so pass the control.

Try:

```
function checkForm(formObj) {

  // Pass the checkbox control using its name
  return checkList(formObj.myCheck); 
}
```

Regarding:

```
> i tried to grab the textfield with syntax as formName.TextareafieldName
```

Documents have a [*forms*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-forms) collection that is all the forms in a document. The members can be referenced by index or by their name or ID. In some browsers, the ID will be made a global variable that references the form but using that feature is considered a bad idea.

You can reference the form using:

```
document.forms.myForm
```

or

```
document.forms[0]
```

assuming it's the first or only form in the document. Similarly, controls can be accessed as named members of the form, so:

```
var form = document.forms[0];
var myCheck = form.myCheck;
```

Forms also have an [*elements*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-form-elements) collection that is all the controls in (or belonging to) the form, so you can also do:

```
var myCheck = form.elements.myCheck;
```

or

```
var myCheck = form.elements[0];
```

if *myCheck* is the first control in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this form for your example...

```
<form>
 First name:<br>
 <input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text">
 <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input name="lastname" type="text">
  </form>
  <br>
  <p>
  <input onchange="checkList(this);return false;" id="change"    type="checkbox">
  <span id="sp-change"></span></p>
```

And here is script Code...

```
function checkList(ch) {
if (ch.checked) {
 var textBox = document.getElementById("firstname");
 var textLength = textBox.value.length;
 if (textLength == 0) {
  window.alert("You have checked the check box;you must provide your name.");
  return false;
  } else {
   window.alert("Success");
  return true;
 }
 }
 return false;
 }
```

I think this help you a lot.

Comment: Wow, you did nothing more than copy-pasting my jsfiddle example from the comment as answer.

Comment: Without even explaining why the OP had an error or why this code fixes it. It's also not particularly elegant.